# Problems with JavaFX dialog

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application with a main window. Upon clicking a "Create User" button, a dialog is shown to get inputs from the user. After the "OK" button on the dialog is clicked, the dialog is disabled and the cursor changed to waiting, while the application does the necessary task to create a new user. If the task is successful, the dialog will be closed, and an information alert will be shown to announce the success.

The following are the codes that I have simplified from my actual codes to reproduce the problems that I have encountered. Here are the problems:

1. Why is dialog.getDialogPane().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT) not working? I am able to change the cursor on the main window with primaryStage.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT). But how do I change the cursor on a dialog?
2. When the alert is displayed, it seems that the dialog may not be closed even though dialog.close() is called before the alert is shown (however, if I make the dialog simpler with just a single button and nothing else, it will disappear when I called dialog.close()). Also, when I drag the alert box around, the dialog and the main window behind it are not refreshed. So it seems that something is not right with the codes.

Codes:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    private Dialog<String> dialog;
    private Button createUserButton = new Button("Create User");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Text usersLabel = new Text("Current Users:");
        TableColumn<User, String> indexColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("No.");
        indexColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 10);
        indexColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().indexProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> userNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("User Name");
        userNameColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 60);
        userNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().userNameProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> roleColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Role");
        roleColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30);
        roleColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().roleProperty());
        TableView<User> tableView = new TableView<User>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(indexColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(userNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(roleColumn);
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        Text dummyLabel = new Text("");
        createUserButton.setOnAction(event -> showDialog());
        VBox leftPane = new VBox(5);
        leftPane.getChildren().addAll(usersLabel, tableView);
        VBox rightPane = new VBox(20);
        rightPane.setFillWidth(true);
        rightPane.getChildren().addAll(dummyLabel, createUserButton);
        GridPane mainPane = new GridPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        mainPane.setHgap(20);
        mainPane.add(leftPane, 0, 0);
        mainPane.add(rightPane, 1, 0);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Create User");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Please enter User Name and Password to create a new user.");
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        Label userNameLabel = new Label("User Name:");
        Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
        TextField userNameField = new TextField();
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 35, 20, 35));
        grid.add(userNameLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(userNameField, 2, 1);
        grid.add(passwordLabel, 1, 2);
        grid.add(passwordField, 2, 2);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        okButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            createUser(userNameField.getText().trim(), passwordField.getText());
            event.consume();
        });
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    private void createUser(String userName, String password) {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(true);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT); // does not work!
        Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000); // simulate processing
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                }
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            Boolean success = task.getValue();
            dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(false);
            dialog.getDialogPane().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            if (success.booleanValue()) {
                dialog.close(); // does not seem to close before alert is shown
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Create User Successful");
                alert.setHeaderText("The user is successfully created.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Create User Error");
                alert.setHeaderText("Unable to create user.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Application.launch(arguments);
    }

}
```

Here are the codes for the User class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class User {

    private StringProperty index;

    private StringProperty userName;

    private StringProperty role;

    public void setIndex(String index) {
        indexProperty().set(index);
    }

    public String getIndex() {
        return indexProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty indexProperty() {
        if (index == null) {
            index = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "index");
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        userNameProperty().set(userName);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty userNameProperty() {
        if (userName == null) {
            userName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "userName");
        }
        return userName;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        roleProperty().set(role);
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return roleProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty roleProperty() {
        if (role == null) {
            role = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "role");
        }
        return role;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

(1) For the cursor problem, I just need to change this line:

```
dialog.getDialogPane().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
```

to:

```
dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT)
```

(2) For the second problem, I just need to change this line:

```
dialog.close();
```

to:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    dialog.close();
});
```

Solution:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    private Dialog<String> dialog;
    private Button createUserButton = new Button("Create User");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Text usersLabel = new Text("Current Users:");
        TableColumn<User, String> indexColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("No.");
        indexColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 10);
        indexColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().indexProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> userNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("User Name");
        userNameColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 60);
        userNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().userNameProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> roleColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Role");
        roleColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30);
        roleColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().roleProperty());
        TableView<User> tableView = new TableView<User>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(indexColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(userNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(roleColumn);
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        Text dummyLabel = new Text("");
        createUserButton.setOnAction(event -> showDialog());
        VBox leftPane = new VBox(5);
        leftPane.getChildren().addAll(usersLabel, tableView);
        VBox rightPane = new VBox(20);
        rightPane.setFillWidth(true);
        rightPane.getChildren().addAll(dummyLabel, createUserButton);
        GridPane mainPane = new GridPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        mainPane.setHgap(20);
        mainPane.add(leftPane, 0, 0);
        mainPane.add(rightPane, 1, 0);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Create User");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Please enter User Name and Password to create a new user.");
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        Label userNameLabel = new Label("User Name:");
        Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
        TextField userNameField = new TextField();
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 35, 20, 35));
        grid.add(userNameLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(userNameField, 2, 1);
        grid.add(passwordLabel, 1, 2);
        grid.add(passwordField, 2, 2);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        okButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            createUser(userNameField.getText().trim(), passwordField.getText());
            event.consume();
        });
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    private void createUser(String userName, String password) {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(true);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT); // Changed
        Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000); // simulate processing
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                }
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            Boolean success = task.getValue();
            dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(false);
            dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT); // Changed
            if (success.booleanValue()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> { // Added
                    dialog.close();
                });                       // Added
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Create User Successful");
                alert.setHeaderText("The user is successfully created.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Create User Error");
                alert.setHeaderText("Unable to create user.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Application.launch(arguments);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your user class.

Comment: I just posted the User class codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still go for disabling the `DialogPane`. However, I presume that by disabling the `DialogPane` you are also preventing it from being hit-tested and thus from receiving any mouse events.

But you could use any parent node (the scene node in this case) of the `DialogPane`:

```
dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(true);
dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing dialog.getDialogPane().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT) to dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT) works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from this line of code:

```
dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(true);
```

Instead of disabling the `DialogPane`, just disable the `Node`s on the `Pane`.

**It seems you have asked more than one question. This answers your `Cursor` question.**